# how to orchestrate processes in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a program to process a `multiprocessing.Queue` by several processes in parallel. The more I dig into the orchestration part, the less I understand.

What I want to achieve is to start several processes and to make sure all of them are done before going further. This sounds like a job for `.join()`.

I ended up by testing the following demo script (ran on a Linux):

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def myproc():
    print("hello from {proc}".format(proc=multiprocessing.current_process()))
    time.sleep(5)

allproc = []
for _ in range(3):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=myproc)
    allproc.append(p)
    p.start()

print("all processes started")

for p in allproc:
    print("joining {proc}".format(proc=p))
    p.join()

print("the end")
```

What I expected is to have the function started three times, immediatly printing the "hello" message and then sleep. Once all of them are done sleeping, the final message ("the end") is printed.

What I actually get is this:

```
hello from <Process(Process-1, started)>
hello from <Process(Process-2, started)>
all processes started
joining <Process(Process-1, started)>
hello from <Process(Process-3, started)>
joining <Process(Process-2, stopped)>
joining <Process(Process-3, stopped)>
the end
```

When running the script, it waits between the 3rd "hello" and the 2nd "joining".

How should I design multiprocessing code so that I can achieve the expected orchestration, per above?

Comment: It seems okay. This is what I believe is happening: the main thread reaches the join line before the third process has time to print it's message, than it hangs. By that time, the third process prints its stuff and waits. Process one ends so the main thread can move on to join the second process, but two is already finished. It then moves to the third process, but that guy is done as well (note the "stopped" status on both cases). Then, the main process leave the premisses.

Comment: I meant the ``premises". Sigh ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is the main thread to wait for all children processes to be done before `print("the end")` then your code is correct, as per the explanation I posted above. If you place a `print len(multiprocessing.active_children())` right before the last line of code, you will see that it is equal to 0.